# importing libraries in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, shared-libraries

I recently migrated from eclipse to studio.. please help me out..

in my project i had imported a date picker library .. I got the following error

```
D:\StudioWorkspace\reminder_app\Reminder\DateTimePicker\build.gradle
Error:(4, 0) Could not find property 'ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION' on project ':DateTimePicker'.
Error:(4, 0) Could not find property 'ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION' on project ':DateTimePicker'.
```

my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 21
  buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.allwyn.reminder"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
   }
}

 dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:1.3.0'
 }
```

my gradle. properties file

```
 ---ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION=19
 ---ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=19
 ---ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION=19
 +++ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION=20
 +++ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=20
 +++ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION=20
```

Comment: where did you put  gradle.properties? In which directory?

Comment: @Blackbelt  gradle.propeties is a direct child of Reminder so the root will be       D:\StudioWorkspace\reminder_app\Reminder\gradle.properties